# Reading javascript variable into shiny/R on app load

Tags: javascript, r, wordpress, shiny, shiny-server

What I want to do is get the user ID from a wordpress logged-in user when I load a shiny app in an iframe. This variable could then be used to save and modify user-specific data.

I have gotten some of the way by adding the following code to the wordpress page:

```
<?php global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo(); 
$user_name = $current_user->user_login; 
$user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 
?>
```

And then this to make it a javascript variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var username = <?php echo json_encode($user_name) ?> ; 
var userID = <?php echo json_encode($user_ID) ?> ; 
</script>
```

Using the example found [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/) I am able to get the variable if I click a div box.

**ui.R:**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI( bootstrapPage(

  # include the js code
  includeScript("get_user_id.js"),

  # a div named mydiv
  tags$div(id="mydiv",
           style="width: 50px; height :50px; left: 100px; top: 100px;
           background-color: gray; position: absolute"),

  # an element for unformatted text
  verbatimTextOutput("results")
))
```

**server.R:**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$results = renderPrint({
    input$mydata
  })
})
```

**get_user_id.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = function() {
  document.domain = "DOMAIN_NAME_HERE"; 
  var username = parent.username; 
  var userID = parent.userID; 
    Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", userID);
  };
});
```

Note that the domain name (or IP) is needed because the shiny app loaded in the iframe is on another port than the wordpress page. The **iframe** should be created by:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.domain = "DOMAIN_NAME_HERE"; 
</script> 
<iframe id="example1" style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 500px;" src="APP_URL" height="150" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But what I want is to just get the variable as soon as the app loads so I can use it in the app to save data to a database etc.
I couldn't find any way to do this. I haven't been able to achieves this using ".onload" or several jquery alternatives I have tried. Any hints would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Also posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/3XM2mHuzqRs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erik Westlund was kind enough to provide the following solution.

**get_user_id.js:**

```
document.domain = "MYDOMAIN.com"; 

var userIDVariableName = parent.userID; 
var userID = document.getElementById("userID"); 
userID.value = userIDVariableName; 

var usernameVariableName = parent.username; 
var username = document.getElementById("username"); 
username.value = usernameVariableName;
```

*As mentioned above remember to change the domain. And set it in the page loading the iframe.*

**ui.R:**

```
library(shiny) 

shinyUI( bootstrapPage( 

# Hidden input boxes to save the variable to 
HTML(‘ <input type="text" id="userID" name="userID" style="display: none;"> ‘), 
HTML(‘ <input type="text" id="username" name="username" style="display: none;"> ‘), 


# include the js code 
includeScript("get_user_id.js"), 

# Show the output 
textOutput("view") 
))
```

*Change the path to the script as needed.*

**server.R:**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 



userID <- reactive({ input$userID }) 
username <- reactive({ input$username }) 

output$view <- renderText( paste0( "User ID is: ",userID()," and username is: ",username() ) ) 

})
```

**Add this to the page containing the iframe:**

*PHP to get the variable from wordpress.*

```
<?php global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo(); 
$user_name = $current_user->user_login; 
$user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 
?>
```

*And then this to make it a java variable:*

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var username = <?php echo json_encode($user_name) ?> ; 
var userID = <?php echo json_encode($user_ID) ?> ; 
</script>
```

*Set domain and the iframe:*

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.domain = "MYDOMAIN.com"; 
</script> 
<iframe id="example1" style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 500px;" src="PATH_TO_SHINY_APP" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `onInputChange` as soon as the Shiny app starts then you need to use the following JavaScript code instead of listening for click events.

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", userID);
  }, 10)
});
```

Comment: Thanks @peter This works like a charm! You don't need any click event for onInputChange