# How to set dateInput maximum to client current date?

Tags: shiny

A simple example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui=fluidPage(
    dateInput("date","Choose a date",max=Sys.Date()),
    textOutput("text")
  ),server = function(input, output) {
    output$text=renderText(as.character(input$date))
  }
)
```

which has a date input. Currently, the latest date is set to the system date, but I want to change this to the client's date. How do i do that?

(I am aware of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842229/how-to-retrieve-the-clients-current-time-and-time-zone-when-using-shiny/24844957#24844957) that talk about how to retrieve client data via javascript, but I don't know how to use those results in a `dateInput` object.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same idea as the first answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842229/how-to-retrieve-the-clients-current-time-and-time-zone-when-using-shiny/24844957#24844957) you posted and use `updateDateInput` in the `server.R` to get the client's date and change the max of your `dateInput`:

```
shinyApp(
  ui=fluidPage(
    HTML('<input type="text" id="client_time" name="client_time" style="display: none;" > '),
    tags$script('
    $(function() {
     var time_now = new Date()
     var month_now=time_now.getMonth()+1
      $("input#client_time").val(time_now.getFullYear()+"-"+month_now+"-"+time_now.getDate())
  });    
'),
    dateInput("date","Choose a date",max=Sys.Date()),
    textOutput("text")
  ),server = function(input, output,session) {
    observe({
    updateDateInput(session,"date", value = as.Date(input$client_time), max = as.Date(input$client_time))
    })
    output$text=renderText(as.character(input$date))
  }
)
```