# Shiny DT: format date column in excel through Buttons extensions

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a datatable with date column that shows UTC timezone.
Using last development version of [DT](https://github.com/rstudio/DT) one can choose to convert date column to locale string and everything shows nicely in shiny webapp. However, if user will download the table through Buttons extension, the date column will be exported in the UTC time zone (and unreadable format)

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:100, b = 1:100, 
             d=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-08-23 10:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2017-11-30 10:00:00"), by = "days"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(df, 
              extensions = c("Buttons"), 
              options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                             buttons = list("csv",list(extend='excel',filename="DF"))
              )) %>% formatDate(3, "toLocaleString", params = list('fr-FR'))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So if local OS time zone is +5, it will show `"23/08/2017 à 10:00:00"` in a shiny webapp, but `"2017-08-23T05:00:00Z"` in excel file. Is there any possible way to format exports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve what you want, I propose two methods, both require you to transform the data set to the user's locale.

#### Using an input

In the same view as the table, provide a shiny input, which allows user selection of the locale. Use this value to transform the UTC entries.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "timezone", "Timezone",
    choices = c("Europe/Paris", "America/Los_Angeles", "Australia/Sydney")
  ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:100,
    b = 1:100, 
    d = seq(
      as.POSIXct("2017-08-23 10:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
      as.POSIXct("2017-11-30 10:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
      by = "days")
  )

  df_locale <- reactive({

    df %>%
      mutate(
        local = format(d, "%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z", tz = input$timezone)
      )

  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      df_locale(),
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = list("copy", "csv", list(extend = "excel", filename = "DF"))
      )
    ) %>%
    formatDate(3, "toLocaleString", params = list("fr-FR"))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Automatically based on the client machine

This is more involved and relies on the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842229/how-to-retrieve-the-clients-current-time-and-time-zone-when-using-shiny) question.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(

  HTML('<input type="text" id="client_time" name="client_time" style="display: none;"> '),
  HTML('<input type="text" id="client_time_zone_offset" name="client_time_zone_offset" style="display: none;"> '),
  tags$script('
  $(function() {
    var time_now = new Date()
    $("input#client_time").val(time_now.getTime())
    $("input#client_time_zone_offset").val(time_now.getTimezoneOffset())
  });    
  '),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:100,
    b = 1:100, 
    d = seq(
      as.POSIXct("2017-08-23 10:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
      as.POSIXct("2017-11-30 10:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
      by = "days")
  )

  client_time <- reactive({as.numeric(input$client_time) / 1000})
  time_zone_offset <- reactive({-as.numeric(input$client_time_zone_offset) * 60})

  df_locale <- reactive({

    df %>%
      mutate(
        local = format(d + seconds(time_zone_offset()), "%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
      )

  })  

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(
      df_locale(),
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = list("copy", "csv", list(extend = "excel", filename = "DF"))
      )
    ) %>%
      formatDate(3, "toLocaleString", params = list("fr-FR"))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

> **N.B.** While the advantage of the automated option is that no user interaction is required, I have not tried to determine the *Olson Name* location of the client and therefore not resolving the time zone beyond a time offset from *UTC*. There are likely options available to improve using alternate *javascript*.

#### Update using download button

If you want to download something different to what is available in the `DT::datatable` via the *Buttons* extension, you have the option to use the standard `downloadHandler` and associated button. In the code below I demonstrate how you can combine your original code to display the table and offer a *csv* download of the data transformed to suit the client time zone offset shown in the previous two approaches.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(

  HTML('<input type="text" id="client_time" name="client_time" style="display: none;"> '),
  HTML('<input type="text" id="client_time_zone_offset" name="client_time_zone_offset" style="display: none;"> '),
  tags$script('
              $(function() {
              var time_now = new Date()
              $("input#client_time").val(time_now.getTime())
              $("input#client_time_zone_offset").val(time_now.getTimezoneOffset())
              });    
              '),
  downloadButton("download_data", "Get Data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){

  df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:100,
    b = 1:100, 
    d = seq(
      as.POSIXct("2017-08-23 10:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
      as.POSIXct("2017-11-30 10:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
      by = "days")
  )

  client_time <- reactive({as.numeric(input$client_time) / 1000})
  time_zone_offset <- reactive({-as.numeric(input$client_time_zone_offset) * 60})

  df_locale <- reactive({

    df %>%
      mutate(
        d = format(d + seconds(time_zone_offset()), "%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
      )

  })

  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
    filename <- function() {
      paste0(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m%d"), "-data.csv")
    },
    content <- function(file) {
      write_csv(df_locale(), file)
    },
    contentType = "text/csv"
  )

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(df) %>%
      formatDate(3, "toLocaleString")

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The *Buttons* extention for `DT` does not currently have the ability to be customised with R. Changing the behaviour may be possible with *javascript*, you can read [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) about the API.

Comment: Great! But the problem is that it converts date class to string format, which leads to issues with filtering and sorting in the shiny app.

Comment: @Asayat, there is no function to obtain the client machine's exact time zone (see my linked question). Without the time zone and only the offset, you can either display as string as I've shown or accept the local time stored as UTC (which is misleading in my opinion). You could continue to display in the table with your original code, but mutate the data frame for download to get the best of both worlds. Otherwise, you will need to write custom javascript, which is beyond the scope of my answer.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm afraid I'm not sure how to mutate for download only, only by using shiny app features, but not DT's buttons extension.